# consul lock not getting released

Tags: consul

I am trying to establish a lock from 2 processes (each process from a different pod). In the first trial, In the first trial, 1 process (assume p1 process got the lock) is getting the lock succesfully. But when I try to kill & start the p1 process, the lock is not getting shifted to the other process (p2) provided the p2 tries for every 5s. Neither process is getting the lock.

In the logs I see the error 'already started' in both the process logs. When I check for the consul process in using `ps -ef` there's nothing there.
And if I try to stop the 2 processes and start both again simultaneously, neither one gets the lock.

```
commad used "/tmp/consul lock -timeout 5s t1 " while :; do sleep 10; done"" FYI, i am tring in golang exec package as
cmd := "/tmp/consul lock -timeout 5s t1 \" while :; do sleep 10; done\""
aa := exec.Command("/bin/sh", "-c", cmd)
aa.Run()
```

Answer (score 0):

> timeout - Maximum amount of time to wait to acquire the lock, specified as a duration like 1s or 3h. The default value is 0.

It looks like you're specifying a timeout of 5s. Once the second process fails to get the lock within 5s, it will stop trying. Additionally, as soon as the process fails to get the lock (because something already has it), I believe that it won't try again. It looks to me like timeout is used to wait for a response from `consul` and once it has that response (either true or false) it will continue.

Rather than using timeout, I think you'll want to use `try`:

> -try - Attempt to acquire the lock up to the given timeout. The timeout is a positive decimal number, with unit suffix, such as "500ms". Valid time units are "ns", "us" (or "µs"), "ms", "s", "m", "h".

https://www.consul.io/docs/commands/lock.html#try